# Testing for cookie existence in Django

Tags: python, django, http, cookies

Simple stuff here...

if I try to reference a cookie in Django via

```
request.COOKIE["key"]
```

if the cookie doesn't exist that will throw a key error.

For Django's `GET` and `POST`, since they are `QueryDict` objects, I can just do

```
if "foo" in request.GET
```

which is wonderfully sophisticated...

what's the closest thing to this for cookies that isn't a Try/Catch block, if anything...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`request.COOKIES` is a standard Python dictionary, so the same syntax works.

Another way of doing it is:

```
request.COOKIES.get('key', 'default')
```

which returns the value if the key exists, otherwise 'default' - you can put anything you like in place of 'default'.

Answer (score 7):

First, it's

```
request.COOKIES
```

not `request.COOKIE`. Other one will throw you an error.

Second, it's a dictionary (or, dictionary-like) object, so:

```
if "foo" in request.COOKIES.keys()
```

will give you what you need.
If you want to get the value of the cookie, you can use:

```
request.COOKIES.get("key", None)
```

then, if there's no key `"key"`, you'll get a `None` instead of an exception.

Comment: Since python 2.2, you can use 'if "foo" in request.COOKIES' -- there's no need to add '.keys()'

Comment: right. Probably it's just me, but I like the longer version more (maybe a matter of working with pre-2.2 for a long time). It's more symmetrical and so more implicit what do I check if I use: in "foo" in dict.keys() and if "bar" in dict.values()...

Comment: @kender, there is just a downside of `"foo" in dict.keys()` - `dict.keys()` creates a list which is then garbage collected - additional overhead.